# How can I compare two dates in the format: "Sun, 20 Jun 2010 10:45:05 GMT" using a XPATH expression?

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

XML sample:

```
<book>
    <item>
      <title>Book One</title> 
      <pubDate>Sun, 20 Jun 2010 10:45:05 GMT</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>Book Two</title> 
      <pubDate>Mon, 21 Jun 2010 11:40:03 GMT</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>Book Three</title> 
      <pubDate>Mon, 05 Jul 2010 10:45:05 GMT</pubDate>
    </item>
</book>
```

I need to retrieve the nodes between two dates, but they are in that format:

```
Sun, 20 Jun 2010 10:45:05 GMT
```

If I try

```
//book/item[pubDate > 'Sun, 20 Jun 2010 10:45:05 GMT' and pubDate < 'Mon, 05 Jul 2010 10:45:05 GMT']/title
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: Share XML sample for those `item` nodes

Comment: Please, take a look!

Comment: You've tagged it XPath 2.0, but if you can move to XPath 3.1, there's a parse-ietf-date() function that should handle this format.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use a commandline tool, then [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel), with its own [`x:parse-dateTime()`](http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-parse-dateTime) function, can do what you want:

```sh
$ xidel -s input.xml -e '
  //book/item[
    x:parse-dateTime(substring-after(pubDate,", "),"dd mmm yyyy hh:nn:ss") ! (
      . > dateTime("2010-06-20T10:45:05") and
      . < dateTime("2010-07-05T10:45:05")
    )
  ]/title
'
Book Two
```

---

From 2019 fastforward to 2021, `xidel` now also supports XPath/XQuery 3.1, so you can use `parse-ietf-date()`, as Michael suggested:

```
//book/item[
  parse-ietf-date(pubDate) ! (
    . > dateTime("2010-06-20T10:45:05Z") and
    . < dateTime("2010-07-05T10:45:05Z")
  )
]/title
```

Or even...

```
//book/item[
  parse-ietf-date(pubDate) ! (
    . > parse-ietf-date("Sun, 20 Jun 2010 10:45:05 GMT") and
    . < parse-ietf-date("Mon, 05 Jul 2010 10:45:05 GMT")
  )
]/title
```